# Listen globally for controller $destroy in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Can you listen for $destroy globally? i.e. When *any* controller is destroyed not just the current controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the broadcast

```
 $scope.$broadcast('destroy');
```

and listen it wherever you want, like this

```
$scope.$on('destroy', function (event, data) {
   // do whatever you want to do
});
```

Comment: Ok, I wanted to avoid having an $on('destroy') on every controller but as a quick fix I'l do that but $emit('destroy') to parent controller